# Regex lookahead logical 'OR' - to exclude certain patterns

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind, positive-lookahead

I've seen a lot of examples of password validation that do a logical AND.
For example, password must have

- AT LEAST one digit (AND)
- AT LEAST one character (AND)
- length between 6 and 15

This can be written with regex 'positive lookahead' as:

```
var includePattern = @"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-z]).{6,15}$"; 
bool tfMatch = Regex.IsMatch("Password1", includePattern); //
if (tfMatch)
    //continue... valid thus far...
```

My question is I want to EXCLUDE certain groups or patterns, in essence doing a logical 'OR'; For example, let's say i want to match (so as to invalidate password if ANY of the following is true):

- AT LEAST one SPACE FOUND (OR)
- at least one single-quote found (OR)
- at least one double-quote found (OR)
- the string "666" number of the beast

Help sought on the excludePattern.. positive lookahead? negative lookahead?

```
var excludePattern = @"^( ...xxx...  $"; //<== **** what goes in here??
bool tfMatch = Regex.IsMatch("Pass 666 word", excludePattern); //
if (tfMatch)
    //DONT continue... contains excluded
```

I am using c# regex, but any flavor will do to get started.

Comment: Just negative lookahead for an alternation between those patterns you want to exclude?

Comment: CertainPerformance.. don't know, no idea where to even start.. as good as a newbie when it comes to regex. If my question is clear, please write as an answer. it may help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you can use multiple positive lookaheads to check that a string fulfills multiple positive patterns, you can alternate inside a negative lookahead to check that none of the alternated patterns inside the lookahead are matched by the string. For example, for your

> AT LEAST one SPACE FOUND (OR)
>
> at least one single-quote found (OR)
>
> at least one double-quote found (OR)
>
> the string "666" number of the beast

You can use

```
^(?!.* |.*'|.*"|.*666)<rest of your pattern>
```

https://regex101.com/r/u9BoIl/1